# Inserting HTML table row with Datepicker doesn't work

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using the Datepicker plugin to insert date values.
I also use a script that allows users to insert cells in an HTML table.

When the user acess the "edit.php" page, they have a table with several `<input type="text">` with information fetched from the database. They can edit it, or insert more data by clicking the "add row" button.

So, if the user wants another row in the table to insert more data into the database, the datepicker plugin doesn't work on the new row.

Here is my datepicker plugin code:

```
$(function() {
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
});
```

And here is the code that allows me to insert more cell rows:

```
function addRow()
{
//add a row to the rows collection and get a reference to the newly added row
var newRow = document.all("tabela1").insertRow(-1);

//add 3 cells (<td>) to the new row and set the innerHTML to contain text boxes

var oCell = newRow.insertCell();
oCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input type='text' name='ippdesc[]'></td>";

oCell = newRow.insertCell();
oCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' name='ippemp[]'></td>";

oCell = newRow.insertCell();
oCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' class='datepicker' name='ippdata[]' value='05-05-2005'></td>";
oCell = newRow.insertCell();
oCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk[]'></td></tr>";

document.getElementById("addr").onclick = doFunction;
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because you're creating the HTML code for the datepicker AFTER the jQuery function has been called. In general, the datepicker-function works by going through the HTML code when the page is loaded and linking the function to all fitting elements (i.e. input items with the class "datepicker"); it will ignore HTML items that were created after the function was called.

So you have to call the datepicker-function again after you've loaded the new row; I would first unbind the datepicker-function to avoid multiple datepickers on the same element, then bind them again (hope that made sense...) Something like this:

```
oCell.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' class='datepicker' name='ippdata[]' value='05-05-2005'></td>";
oCell = newRow.insertCell();
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
```